# Django: AJAX code needed for dependent dropdowns

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, database, dropdown

Since I'm new to Django and have absolutely no knowledge of JS/AJAX, I'm trying to code in the most simple possible way dependent dropdowns. I managed to get my dropdowns populated with values from my database (data_immo). Now I need to have the second dropdown updated after user selection in the first one.

Here is my home.html file with the two dropdowns (regions and departements):

```
<select name="regions" id="regions">
  {% for item in query_results_dict %}
  <option value={{ item.nom_reg }}>{{ item.nom_reg }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="departements" id="departements">
  {% for item in departements %}
  <option val="{{ item.insee_dep }}"> {{ item.insee_dep }} </option>    
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

views.py:

```
def MyView(request):

    query_results = data_immo.objects.all()
    regions = data_immo.objects.values_list("nom_reg", flat=True).distinct()
    departements = data_immo.objects.values_list("insee_dep", flat=True).distinct()

    query_results_dict = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'regions': regions,
        'departements': departements,
    }

    return render(request,'home.html', query_results_dict)
```

models.py:

```
class data_immo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    insee_dep = models.IntegerField(db_column='INSEE_DEP', blank=True, null=True) 
    nom_reg = models.TextField(db_column='NOM_REG', blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'immo'
```

My understanding is that I need to retrieve the selected value from the "regions" dropdown and use an onChange function to trigger an action that will use that variable and inspect the db so only matching depatements are selected. Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed. I know there are a few examples out there, but none of them were really satisfying, and those I tried failed due to my lack of JS/AJAX knowledge.
Let me know if need more details.

EDIT 1: added models.py; also, the website that has been recommended in the comments has values stored in different tables whereas mine are all in the same one. Surely this must have an impact on my code and cannot be replicated per se.

Comment: [here is a depended dropdown tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: I was about to comment the same @suhailvs

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but it's very different to my code and too difficult for me to adapt considering my level. Wouldn't it be possible for a simple Ajax/Js code snippet to perform what I would need?